# WHERE IN (SELECT) statement breaks query, when there is a WITH statement present

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, alasql

This works perfectly:

```
SELECT qaer_name, 
       AVG(Minutes(QA_Time)) AS avg_minutes, 
       COUNT(Zendesk_URL) AS num_tickets
FROM zendeskData
WHERE qaer_name IN (SELECT Name FROM qaers)
AND tags LIKE '%cosmetic%'                    
AND CAST(sub_to_qa_date AS DATE) >= CAST('${new Date('2021-11-10')}' AS DATE)
GROUP BY qaer_name
```

But this breaks with the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

```
WITH cosmetic AS (
  SELECT qaer_name, 
         AVG(Minutes(QA_Time)) AS avg_minutes, 
         COUNT(Zendesk_URL) AS num_tickets
  FROM zendeskData
  WHERE qaer_name IN (SELECT Name FROM qaers)
  AND tags LIKE '%cosmetic%'                    
  AND CAST(sub_to_qa_date AS DATE) >= CAST('${new Date('2021-11-10')}' AS DATE)
  GROUP BY qaer_name
)
SELECT * FROM cosmetic
```

This one doesn't give an error (but doesn't do the filtering I want):

```
WITH cosmetic AS (
  SELECT qaer_name, 
         AVG(Minutes(QA_Time)) AS avg_minutes, 
         COUNT(Zendesk_URL) AS num_tickets
  FROM zendeskData
  --WHERE qaer_name IN (SELECT Name FROM qaers)
  WHERE tags LIKE '%cosmetic%'                    
  AND CAST(sub_to_qa_date AS DATE) >= CAST('${new Date('2021-11-10')}' AS DATE)
  GROUP BY qaer_name
)
SELECT * FROM cosmetic
```

But, this one does give the same error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

```
WITH cosmetic AS (
  SELECT qaer_name, 
         AVG(Minutes(QA_Time)) AS avg_minutes, 
         COUNT(Zendesk_URL) AS num_tickets
  FROM zendeskData
  WHERE tags LIKE '%cosmetic%'                    
  AND CAST(sub_to_qa_date AS DATE) >= CAST('${new Date('2021-11-10')}' AS DATE)
  GROUP BY qaer_name
)
SELECT * 
FROM cosmetic
WHERE qaer_name IN (SELECT Name FROM qaers)
```

Why does the `WHERE IN (SELECT)` statement break it only when there is a `WITH` statement present?

Edit:
This also gives the same error.

```
let data = Database.alasql(`
  ;WITH cosmetic AS (
    SELECT qaer_name, 
          AVG(Minutes(QA_Time)) AS avg_minutes, 
          COUNT(Zendesk_URL) AS num_tickets
    FROM zendeskData z
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM qaers q WHERE z.qaer_name = q.Name) 
    AND tags LIKE '%cosmetic%'                    
    AND CAST(sub_to_qa_date AS DATE) >= CAST('${new Date('2021-11-10')}' AS DATE)
    GROUP BY qaer_name
  )
  SELECT * 
  FROM cosmetic
`);
Logger.log(data);
```

Comment: Your `IN` will always break.  `IN` matches your field to your `subquery return field` in this case all fields which is wrong.

Comment: ```IN``` does not always break. It does not break in the first example. I made an edit to be more clear that ```SELECT * FROM qaers``` was actually a table with a single field. Running the edited ```SELECT Name FROM qaers``` gives the same error.

Comment: can you change your `with` to `;with` and see what happens?

Comment: Ran it as shown in the Edit, with the same error as a result.

Comment: Your ```WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM qaers q WHERE z.qaer_name = q.Name)``` does give the same result as my ```WHERE qaer_name IN (SELECT Name FROM qaers)``` in the first variation without ```WITH``` though.

Comment: I believe you, and your way is probably better optimized, but the point is it's not what's causing my error. Or at least your method doesn't fix it~

Comment: correct.. but the execution plan is different

Comment: might be your database engine does not support subqueries

Comment: That's my only guess as well. That for some reason Alasql doesn't support CTEs and Subqueries at the same time. Which is very odd, because it does support them separately.

Comment: https://github-wiki-see.page/m/agershun/alasql/wiki/WITH

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the definition of "self-referencing", I still don't see why what I have shouldn't work, but I was able to devise a work around for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why my original method didn't work, but I have devised a work around.

My alternative to making a `qaers` table, and then selecting that table in a future query, is to make the table a JS array and then pass that into the query formatting it as a list.

This gives the proper result I am looking for, because it allows me to use the list of names and a `WITH` statement, which will be necessary as I make the query more complicated.

```
let qaers = Database.alasql(`
  SELECT MATRIX Name 
  FROM annotatorData 
  WHERE Pod_Number = 'QA'
`);

let data = Database.alasql(`
  WITH cosmetic AS (
    SELECT qaer_name, 
          AVG(Minutes(QA_Time)) AS avg_minutes, 
          COUNT(Zendesk_URL) AS num_tickets
    FROM zendeskData
    WHERE qaer_name IN ('${qaers.join("','")}')
    AND tags LIKE '%cosmetic%'                    
    AND CAST(sub_to_qa_date AS DATE) >= CAST('${new Date('2021-11-10')}' AS DATE)
    GROUP BY qaer_name
  )
  SELECT * 
  FROM cosmetic
`)
```

Comment: Use `exists` instead of `in` if alasql supports it

Comment: The EXISTS clause is much faster than IN when the subquery results is very large. Conversely, the IN clause is faster than EXISTS when the subquery results is very small. [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_exists_clause_vs_in_clause.htm#:~:text=The%20EXISTS%20clause%20is%20much%20faster%20than%20IN%20when%20the%20subquery%20results%20is%20very%20large.%20Conversely%2C%20the%20IN%20clause%20is%20faster%20than%20EXISTS%20when%20the%20subquery%20results%20is%20very%20small.) My subquery results are small.